# Bluespec $display within function

Tags: hdl, bluespec

Bluespec complains when I try to use $display within a function definition.

It is only allowed within a rule definition.

Is there a way that I can get to display variable names within a function?

I think it might be using the ActionValue#  but I cannot get the syntax right. I also cannot find examples online.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One correct syntax is -

```
function ActionValue#(rtype) func(...)
= actionvalue
    do something;
    $display(...);
    return val;
endactionvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

A Bluespec function is pure by default. If you want to debug it, split it up into several pieces, save the function result in a field and extract it to your testbench with a method.

Check out the book [Bluespec by Example](http://csg.csail.mit.edu/6.S078/6_S078_2012_www/resources/bsv_by_example.pdf).

$display is a function with a side effect, so it has to be called within an "action" block.

Comment: It can also be called within an actionvalue block if the function returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

Bluespec functions are statically elaborated at compile time, so in general it does not make sense to use `$display` statements inside them. However, if the function returns an `Action` or `ActionValue`, the action it returns *can* contain a `$display` statement, which will then be elaborated inside any rules or methods which call it.

The syntax for creating an `ActionValue` is:

```
actionvalue
    //Anything that can go in a rule body can go here.
    $display(...);
    return value;
endactionvalue
```

The syntax for a plain `Action` is similar, but with `action`/`endaction` and no `return` statement.

This can then be used in a function definition like so:

```
function ActionValue#(Type) funcName(Type arg);
    ...
    return actionvalue
        ...
    endactionvalue;
endfunction
```

If you only need the return statement, you can also use the alternative syntax:

```
function ActionValue#(Type1) funcName(Type2 arg) =
actionvalue
    ...
endactionvalue;
```

One final point, if you actually want to generate output from functions at compile time, you can use the `message` function. However, note that this only takes a simple `String` argument, rather than handling formatting like `$display` does.